# run program as non system

Tags: jenkins, windows-10, background-process

I am using Windows 10. I am running chrome as "userA" and launching Jenkins. The Jenkins is running as "System" process. 
If I am running notepad from Jenkins it is run as "System" because of which it is not visible on desktop. I can see from task manager, that it is running in background.
Is there anyway to get notepad on desktop ?
If Jenkins is run as "userA" will notepad be launched as "userA" process and will be displayed on desktop ?

Comment: to downgrade the permissions, I create a temporary scheduled task that runs with user permissions and run this the other program with less permissions.

Comment: Surely it is running as a service.  Runs in session 0 with its own desktop and no option to interact with the user's desktop.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Thanks for suggestion. Can you explain me how to do this ? Do we need to enter username & password everytime for that ?

Comment: Here is a link on how to create tasks: https://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/ and here is how to run as a specific user: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/schtasks.php#Run

Comment: Hi All, what was the solution to this problem. Am facing a similar issue and am in need of urgent help.